# Change line spacing in docx using ReporteRs in R

Tags: r, docx, spacing, reporters

I'm creating a word document using the ReporteRs package in R, and I want to change the spacing of a paragraph from single spaced to 1.5 spaced.

I guess I could enter each line as a new paragraph and put a buffer at the start of each of those "paragraphs" but I'm looking for a cleaner way.

I'm open to using another package if it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a paragraph with line space 1.5 (with name `myparag`) in an empty Word document and reuse it as a template (filename: `template.docx`).

```
doc <- docx() 
styles( doc ) # check value `myparag` is in the available paragraph styles
doc <- addParagraph(doc, "Blah blah blah", stylename = "myparag")
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for my paragraph, but the same technique doesn't work to change the spacing in the footnote contained in that paragraph. The footnote style seems to be determined by the paragraph style, but I want a single spaced footnote with the reference to that footnote located in a 1.5 spaced paragraph. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

```
## docx example 
doc = docx( )

# Footnote definition
par1 = pot("About this reference", textItalic(font.size = 8) )
par2 = pot("Omni ab coalitos pro malivolus obsecrans graviter 
           cum perquisitor perquisitor pericula saepeque inmunibus coalitos ut.", 
           textItalic(font.size = 8) )

Footnote = Footnote( )
Footnote = addParagraph( Footnote, set_of_paragraphs( par1, par2 ), 
  parProperties(padding.top = 15))

# add text in the doc with previously defined footnote
my_pot = pot("Blah blah blah." ) + 
  pot(" Here is a note.", footnote = Footnote)
doc = addParagraph(doc, my_pot )

writeDoc( doc, file = "footnote.docx" )
```